# importing the library into the header in loop

Tags: reactjs

I have two sepearte file:

- page.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import { MenuModalData } from './data';
d
export default function App() {
  return  (
  <>
  {Object.entries(MenuModalData).map(([key, value]) => {
      return (
        <>
        <div>
          {value?.icon && <value.icon size="1.6rem" className="my-auto" />}
        </div>
        </>
      )
  })}
  </>
  )
}
```

- data.js

```
export const MenuModalData = [
  {
    type: "menu",
    name: "Products",
    page: "/shop",
  },
  {
    type: "menu",
    name: "Contact",
    icon: "BiChat",
    page: "/shop",
  }
]
```

How I can import react-icons `BiChat` by lines similar with import to header in file?

```
{value?.icon && <value.icon size="1.6rem" className="my-auto" />}
```

p.s

- interactive version on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-huznte)

Answer (score 0):

You can import your icon in your data.js file like this :

```
import { BiChat } from "react-icons/bi";

export const MenuModalData = [
  {
    type: "menu",
    name: "Products",
    page: "/shop"
  },
  {
    type: "menu",
    name: "Contact",
    icon: BiChat,
    page: "/shop"
  }
];
```

By the way you can replace

```
Object.entries(MenuModalData).map(([key, value]) => {
```

by :

```
MenuModalData.map((value) => {
```

Comment: Okay, but if I want to import this json from graphql, how can I import "import { BiChat} from "react-icons/bi";`?